# "Towards LATEX coding standards" in TUGboat - Any update?

Tags: untagged

Is there any update of the article *"Towards LaTeX coding standards"* by Didier Verna which is available on http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-3?

I am particularly interested in the naming of macros and environments, as I will be coding behind the scenes via `LaTeX3` which offers a consistent coding style.

Comment: you could ask [the author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24506/didier-verna) but it's very old and was just some personal suggestions not any standard coding guidelines.

Comment: I think this is something missing.

Comment: well as you comment  expl3 does have guidelines, for the rest there is probably not a lot that can be said. Even the main suggestion in that paper of prefixing package commands has to be only selectively appled. Sometimes it makes sense  `\LTleft`,  `\LTright` from `longtable` but I doubt anyone would want thousands of math commands to  get `unicode-math` or `amssymb` prefixes.